# going through such an experience

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

a. Going through such a traumatic experience is difficult to describe.

b. To go through such a traumatic experience is difficult to describe.

I think (a) is grammaticak and natural and (b) is not.

Would you agree with that?

Many thanks

Comment: Please indicate your research on this issue. Why do you think that (a) is grammatical and natural but (b) isn't? That information that will help people to write better answers.

Comment: Also, did you look through existing ELL questions with that tag? This question seems to be a duplicate. (For example: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/95660/to-infinitive-as-a-subject)

Comment: Thank you very much. I hadn't seen the other threads because my title didn't lead me to them. For some reason, I didn't find (a) natural, but I guess that was just me. It seems (judging by the replies in the other threads) that it is grammatical although a bit formal and less common than (a). I hadn't done any research on the subject. I just had a feeling, that apparently was not good!

Comment: *grammaticak* is a delightful portmanteau

Answer (score 0):

Version A is correct, but in this case a native speaker would use extraposition:

> **It** is difficult **to describe  going** through such a traumatic experience.

Comment: Thank you so much Alphabet. I meant to say I didn't find (b) natural. My apologies.